# How to prevent compiler doing implicit typecasting in for the class constructor argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct testarray{
    int element;
public:
    testarray(int a):element(a){}
};
class myarray 
{ 
public:
    testarray i; 

    public: 
            myarray(testarray a) : i(a){ } 


} ;
int main()
{
    myarray objArray[3] = {1,2,3};

    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine in Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition IDE. But what I want is to prevent the compiler from implicitly typecasting the object type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `explicit` keyword for your struct constructor.

Answer (score 9):

Use the keyword `explicit` for `testarray` constructor so that the compiler doesn't perform implicit conversions. Basically you need to write the constructor as:

```
explicit testarray(int a):element(a){}
```

Comment: More generally, always write constructor that can be invoke with a single parameter (taking default values into account) as `explicit`. And evaluate carefully if can take the `explicit` out before removing it, it might save some typing but it WILL introduce bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

yes, use the keyword "explicit" as stated above.
one more suggestion about the source you've provided: why do you have the "public" in the struct? All struct's members are public by default. if you want to have smth with different access modifiers (say, several "private" members or methods), you're better off to use classes.

Comment: thanks for the observation code was written purely written for experimental purpose but i understand that still i should have coded it neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the constructor to be `explicit`?

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/explicit